# How to hide signup/signin link when signed in instead show logout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have site with signin and sign up forms init. I m using session inthe code. 
Now i have tried javascript to achieve this hide and show effect for sign in to logout and vice versa, but the it didn't work. 
Any help is appreciated..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("logout").hide();
        $(".signin").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).parent().find(".logout").show();
            });         
        $(".logout").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).parent().find(".signin").show();
            });
        });
</script>
```

been trying with this code...

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us?

Comment: For god say, Put your code on SO before questioning about anything.

Comment: this isn't enough code to know how to solve your problem. where is the session code? My idea would be to use an if condition. If user signed in, do this and that html else do this and that. 
Post the whole webpage code including the session section.

Comment: Did you notice the first script tag is malformed?